# Solve using constraints of rods

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, constrained-dynamics

Four rigid rods, $OA$, $AB$, $BQ$ and $CD$ are connected as shown in figure. All functions are movable $C$ is mid point of rod $AB$ and $C$ is movable link. The end $D$ of rod $CD$ is constrained to move vertically. For the position shown angular velocity of rod $OA$ is $60\ \text{rev/min}$ clockwise.  If $OA$ = $1$ $m$, $AB$ = $1.6$ $m$, $QB$ = $1.2$ $m$, $OQ$ = $2.4$ $m$ and $CD$ = $2$ $m$. At the instant shown answer the following:

$(1)$ What is the speed of point $D$ ?

$(2)$ What is angular velocity of rod $BQ$ ?

[image: Diagram]

I don't have any idea how to use constraint relations in this question, kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You have five relative motions and three constraint equations thus two  generalized coordinate.

The equations for the relative motion (red Color) describe a „pendulum“ equation. The deflections towards x and y at point Q and D (Blue color) are the constraint equations.

Comment: Can you elaborate your explanation please

Comment: Without constraint , the Rotation of rod OA is angle 1, the rotation of rod AC relative to rod OA is angle 2 and so on, thus you have 5 degrees of freedom, the constraint equations give you 3 equations, 5-3=2 generalized coordinates